# @import doesn't seem to work even though I have the correct setup

Tags: html, css, import, stylesheet

I'm trying to import multiple css files into my html using @import but for some reason it doesn't work.
A tree of my project looks something like this:

```
root
--assets
----css
------body.css
------main.css
--index.html
```

My main.css looks like this: `@import "body.css";`

I put this line in the header in the index `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">`

And for some reason the styles in my body.css aren't showing up.

I did recently get a new laptop, is there any configuration/download I need to do that I just forgot needs to be done?

Comment: what does the network tab of your dev tools say? can the file be loaded? Or do you get a 404?

Comment: I get this error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: What's the path it tries to load?

Comment: Could it be because I just started this project and working on a branch. So the master branch is still empty but a readme file

Comment: No, your browser doesn't care about any branches or whatever. it only cares about if it can load a file. So, what's the path it tries to load?

Comment: Oh yea it was missing 'assets'. But it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the solution to this would be to use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">`

Also on how to find such issues the next time: Press F12 in your browser, navigate to the network tab and reload your site. If you see a red entry there it means it couldn't be loaded (or there were other errors with it)

If it's a 404 error (like `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` )this is your hint that it literally can't find the file. in 99.9999% it's a wrong url. You can even copy-paste the URL and open it on it's own.